# Split values using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, regex, powershell

I have a file with multiple expressions like "$REGX('CareMedic.2_0','CustomerInformation','Customer Information')". The file can be a xml file, text file or any other type. If the file contains 9 of those expressions, I'm trying to pull all nine and send the values to a database.

I've tried my code as below:

```
 $input_path = ‘C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2.xml’

$SQLServer = "WIN-17V7QT0IJVK"
$SQLDBName = "Test"
$uid ="WIN-17V7QT0IJVK\Administrator"
$pwd = "letmebackinplease"
$SqlQuery = "SELECT * from product_schema;"
$ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True;"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString
$SqlConnection.open() 

if($SqlConnection.state -eq "Open"){
    Write-Host "Test connection successful"


}

$regex =  '()\(.*?\)'
$output = select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $.Matches } | % { $.Value } |
ForEach-Object {
        ($_ -split "\(|\)")[1]
    }

foreach ($line in $output){
        $line = $line -replace "\(",""
        $line = $line -replace "\)",""
        $line = $line -replace "\'",""
        $col1,$col2,$col3 = $line -split ","
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            col1 = $col1
            col2 = $col2
            col3 = $col3
            } | select col1,col2,col3

        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO [$SQLDBName].[dbo].[product_schema]
           ([version]
           ,[field]
           ,[value])
     VALUES
          ($col1, $col2, $col3);" 

         $execute_query = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
         $execute_query.connection = $SQLConnection
         $execute_query.commandtext = $insert_query
         $execute_query.ExecuteNonQuery()

}

$SqlConnection.close()
```

If the file has two of the below:

```
('Medic.2_0','AgeInformation','Age Information')
('Medic.2_0','TransactionID','Transaction ID')
```

My actual output should be:

```
'Medic.2_0' stored in Version Column
'AgeInformation' stored in the Field Column
'Age Information' stored in the value column

'Medic.2_0' stored in Version Column
'TransactionID' stored in the Field Column
'Transaction ID' stored in the value column
```

I have to take each of the values and store it in a column in a temp table setup on MySQL server like below:

```
**Version**          **Field**            **Value**

Medic.2_0   AgeInformation      Age Information
Medic.2_0   TransactionID       Transaction ID
```

Error Encountered:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near '.2'."
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.ps1:47 char:10
+          $execute_query.ExecuteNonQuery()
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Can someone please recommend how shall I change my code to solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `export-csv` cmdlet?

Comment: @shadow2020 I know how to export it out to a file if it is a TXT. I have to strip those values and send it out a temporary table on the database. That table will have three columns.

Comment: what does your xml file look like? Or your input more specifically?

Comment: @shadow2020 The input file can be of any data type which is why I used regular expressions to detect a pattern so it can pull out those values. The objective is to strip out all lables like ('Medic.2_0','AgeInformation','Age Information'). Once I get a list of labels, I have to strip out the three values and store each in a given row which is tied to a table

Comment: I get that you have it where you want it so far, but there are probably better ways to get the info into an object which is what you need. As it stands it's not really easy with the output you have. I was hoping to see the input so I could work with more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code:

```
$info=@() #for store your values

foreach($item in $output){
$z=$item.split(',') #for split to 3 strings
$info+=[PSCustomObject]@{ #create custom object which have named columns and store our values
            Version = $z[0]
            Field = $z[1]
            Value = $z[2]
            }

}
Write-Output $info #variable that store all columns
```

Then you must run foreach loop to each object in `$info` . 
you can run it like this:

```
foreach($data in $info){
$data.Version #to access Version field
$data.Field   #to access Field field
$data.Value   #to access Value field
.......your SQL query......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your original question before editing: Assuming your output looks like this and is saved in a variable named `$output`

('Medic.2_0','AgeInformation','Age Information')
('Medic.2_0','TransactionID','Transaction ID')

Try this:

```
foreach ($line in $output){
        $line = $line -replace "\(",""
        $line = $line -replace "\)",""
        $line = $line -replace "\'",""
        $col1,$col2,$col3 = $line -split ","
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            col1 = $col1
            col2 = $col2
            col3 = $col3
            } | select col1,col2,col3 | export-csv d:\test.csv -append -NoTypeInformation
        }
```

We are looping through the `$output` line by line removing the brackets and the single quotes, splitting the remaining text on the comma, then assigning each of the three entries into the relevant variables.  Once they are in variables we can then easily create a PSObject and use it to select our requirements for our `export-csv`

Comment: I'm trying to send each value to the database. Please look at my updated code which already stores each parameter in a variable

Comment: Notice how in my answer how it has been converted into a PSObject - you can do what you want with it as an object.  I don't know SQL well but select the relevant value and send it where you want